# How to filter REST API JSON result by passing params

Tags: rest, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to consume JIRA 2 API and trying to get custom fields. I want to further filter by passing appropriate criteria in URI itself. Current query I'm using is something similar to this:

```
http://localhost:8522/jira522/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?expand=projects.issuetypes.fields
```

The result I'm getting from above request is about 2000 lines.. How can I further filter to get only Custom_fields and also under custom fields I need to only the ones which are required?

I'm pretty new to REST API. Please guide me If anything is wrong... TIA. I spent a lot of time browsing but don't know what exactly I need to search for or where exactly I need to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another queryParam just like expand and add further filtering or pagination.

http://localhost:8522/jira522/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?expand=projects.issuetypes.fields&limit=1000